# How do I do Ruby on Rails concurrency testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, concurrency, race-condition

What is the best way to do concurrency testing with ruby on rails 3?  I have many race conditions on my site and currently testing them is a inexact science that is very time consuming.

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that [Tourbus](https://github.com/dbrady/tourbus/) can help.

Comment: Can you provide some context to this answer?  How do I test race conditions with this?

Comment: Can you provide some context to your question? :) If I get it right, then if some users do something simultaneously, it can cause a race condition. So with Tourbus you can simulate a load of users doing some pre-defined things in parallel. It should trigger the bug if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

I recently published a post with a solution on how to test concurrency caused by job queue workers in order to validate code fix for race condition. It should apply to other concurrency issues in Rails.

http://ternarylabs.com/2012/04/16/handle-job-queue-workers-concurrency-in-rails/

Answer (score 1):

I would look at using the Apache Bench tool.  It should come installed with an Apache installation. Even though it's written by Apache, it is generic enough to test any type of server.

Usage is similar to this

`ab -c 1000 -n 10000 http://www.some-site.cc/`

The "c" is number of concurrent connections and "n" is number of requests.  See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html

Comment: This looks like load testing not concurrency testing to test against race conditions.

Comment: Don't you need multiple requests if you want to test a race condition?

Comment: @Elyasin Yes, but a test needs to be reproducible.  Can you guarantee a race condition will occur every time using ab?  Sure, we can submit so many concurrent requests to make it statistically very likely that a race condition will occur, but we can't necessarily guarantee it.  Additionally, this sort of testing does lend itself well to automation, and is very slow -- something we want to avoid in a test suite.

Answer (score 0):

This blog post has some interesting solutions you may use:

http://blog.ardes.com/2006/12/12/testing-concurrency-in-rails-using-fork